# Array of counters in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to implement array of counters which will hold in every position the number of times each element appear in the array.

for example i have this outcome:

[image: outcome]

from this firestore query:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("confirmed-appointments").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      let arrayofServices = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        arrayofServices.push(doc.data().serviceType)
      })
      console.log("Array of services ", arrayofServices);
      setServices(arrayofServices);
    })
    
  }, [])
```

I want to create an array that will hold a counter for every serviceType i have in my database.

I Think it might be easier to create an object that hold the name of the service and the counter, but i cant figure out how to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arrayofServices = ['osher', 'osher', 'yanir', 'dor', 'osher'];

const servicesCounter = arrayofServices.reduce((counterObj, service) => {
  if (counterObj.hasOwnProperty(service)) {
    counterObj[service] += 1;
    return counterObj;
  }

  return {
    ...counterObj,
    [service]: 1
  };
}, {});

console.log(servicesCounter);
```

Comment: Amazing its working! do you know how can i get the Max,Min and Max - 1 values?
Max will be 3
Min will be 1 
Max - 1 = 2nd most used service

Comment: Depending on what you need it for and the format you need (just the number, the service name plus the number, just the service name), you can retrieve the max and min in different ways: basically you would convert the `serviceCounter` object into an array (using `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` or `Object.entries()`) and either sort it or spread it as arguments for `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`.

Comment: Im kind of new in javascript, learning it as the project goes on so i will try implement as you suggested, i need only the value, i saved the service names in different array

Comment: Yep, that is the correct approach, especially if you are trying to learn javascript; try it yourself first, then you are welcome to ask if you get stuck. ;)

Comment: i Used this: const serviceCounterArray = Object.entries(servicesCounter); and then  const minUsed = Math.min(...serviceCounterArray); its return a "NaN"

Comment: That is because `Object.entries()` returns an array of arrays in the form `[[key, value], [key, value], ...]`; if you are interested only in the values, you should use `Object.values()`.